# PPViewHashesDon'tMatch Exception on submit transaction for Cardano serialization-lib version 10.0.x

Tags: transaction, cardano-serialization-lib

On emurgo/cardano serialization versions 10.0.X receiving error on submit transaction that:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SNpM1LtEDPnZPMQXdz1X_Ujiy_FW9BJW/view?usp=sharing

Also, in emurgo/cardano-serialization version 10.2.0 there is a function in TransactionBulderConfigBuilder.ex_unit_prices() that takes ExUnitPrices Instance, what is the numerator and denominator in ExUnitPrices.new() function, how can one calculates them?

Comment: Hello, beacuse this is your first question I have been asked by the site to review it. It seems there are two questions here and they are not tightly related. In addition if the first question requires a lot to answer the second one might be drowned by the first. It might be better to separate the two into 2 questions.